# How to fix undefined reference to QSerialPortInfo?

Tags: cmake, serial-port, qt5

I have the following error:

```
*.cpp:*: undefined reference to `QSerialPortInfo::QSerialPortInfo()'
```

This question was already on this form, but I have a cmake build system.
I am using the following cmake code to enable:

```
find_package (Qt5 CONFIG REQUIRED Core Widgets Gui SerialPort)
```

Answer (score 0):

add or edit

```
target_link_libraries(yourproj Qt5::Widgets Qt5::SerialPort)
```